# Can Firebase Test Lab test a Jetpack Compose app?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, firebase-test-lab

I have an app built with Jetpack Compose. On the first screen I have a sign in with Google button. I see that Robo tries to click on that but when the Google pop-up appears to select the Google account, nothing happens.

Can Firebase Test Lab test my app? Or only works with traditional views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Jetpack Compose just render down to the same old widgets as any other Android app - which means Firebase Test Lab should be able to test them just fine.

A quick search for [articles/questions about the combination](https://www.google.com/search?q=Can+Firebase+Test+Lab+test+a+Jetpack+Compose+app), seems to confirm that. Like:

- [Running UI tests in Jetpack Compose using Firebase Test Lab](https://victorbrandalise.com/running-ui-tests-in-jetpack-compose-using-firebase-test-lab/)
- [Can Firebase Test Lab test a Jetpack Compose app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78102163/can-firebase-test-lab-test-a-jetpack-compose-app) (check the comment on app architecture)
- [Android: Compose UI Screenshot Testing with Firebase Test Lab and CircleCI](https://medium.com/@daniel.nesfeder/android-compose-ui-screenshot-testing-with-firebase-test-lab-and-circleci-a4a7165cf3e4)